# VSCode combine remote ssh and remote containers

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, ssh

On my office desktop machine, I'm running a docker container that accesses the GPU. Now, since I'm working from home, I'm connected through ssh to my office desktop computer in vs code via remote ssh plugin which works really well. However, I would like to further connect via remote containers to that running container in order to be able to debug the code I'm running in that container. Failed to get this done yet.

Anyone has any idea if this is possible at all and in case any idea how to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install and activate ssh server in a container.
2. Expose ssh port via docker
3. create user with home directory and password in container
4. (install remote ssh extension for vs code and) setup ssh connection within the remote extension in vs code and add config entry:

   ```
     Host <host>-docker
     Hostname your.host.name
     User userIdContainer
     Port exposedSshPortInContainer
   ```
5. Connect in vs code.

<sub>*Note: Answer provided by OP on question section.*</sub>